# modalBottomSheet + ListView, how to sync scroll?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-listview

I have a modalBottomSheet with a scrolling list view inside of it.

I want for the scroll control to be transferred to the bottom sheet when the listView reaches the top, so that it can be dragged to dismiss.

Now, the listView gets to the top and even if I keep dragging the bottom sheet will not be dismissed on drag.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include a sample widget that will reproduce the same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      maxChildSize: 1,
      initialChildSize: .5,
      expand: false,
      builder: (context, scrollController) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 44,
          controller: scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text("item $index"),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Freaking incredible. Thanks! Works just how I need it to.